# 2 Dimension Arrays memory segment fault in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I made dynamic allocation and array initialization functions with cpp, but I got a segmentation error The code I wrote is below.

```
#include <iostream>

#define User_Height 100
#define User_Width 100

using namespace std;
 
void Creat_Array(int** _pp_Created_Array)
{
    _pp_Created_Array = new int*[User_Width];

    for (int x = 0; x < User_Height ; x++)
    {
        _pp_Created_Array[x] = new int[User_Height];
    }

    if(_pp_Created_Array == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"""fail to alloc memory.""" <<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {   
        cout << "[_pp_Created_Array] memory first address : ";
        cout << _pp_Created_Array << endl << endl;
    }
}


void Initialize_Array(int** _pp_Initialized_Array)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < User_Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < User_Height; y++)
        {
            _pp_Initialized_Array[x][y] = 0; //*segment fault*
        }
    }
}
```

And I checked the function function created

```
int main()
{
    //debug
    int** debugArray = nullptr;

    cout << "start creat array" <<endl;
    Creat_Array(debugArray);

    cout << "start initial array" <<endl;
    Initialize_Array(debugArray);

    return 0;
}
```

and compile console is (VScode , g++)

```
start creat array
[_pp_Created_Array] memory first address : 0x8a6f40

start initial array
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c cmd /C 
C:\Users\pangpany\project\PathfinderTest\main" failed to launch (exit code: 
3221225477).
```

But I got a segment fault error in void Initialize_Array(int** _pp_Initialized_Array) function
I can't figure out  is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you never return the array from the `Creat_Array` function. and so when you come to use the array you are using an uninitialised variable.

Write `Creat_Array` with a return value instead of a parameter, like this

```
int** Creat_Array()
{
    int** _pp_Created_Array = ...;
    ...
    return _pp_Created_Array;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "start creat array" <<endl;
    int** debugArray = Creat_Array();
    ...
}
```

Changing a variable **inside** a function does not change any variable **outside** the function. `debugArray` and `_pp_Created_Array` are two different variables.

Also this code is wrong

```
if(_pp_Created_Array == NULL)
```

`new` never returns `NULL` so this test will always be false. If `new` fails it throws an exception, it doesn't return `NULL`.

Comment: I am a programming non-major.
And I am a beginner with less than 3 months of programming in c++, so thank you for your help. 
I also learned from the answers how silly questions I am asking.
 But I didn't even know it was stupid when I was coding myself.
 Thank you, experienced coding programmer.

Comment: @wkCHO Don't be too hard on yourself. Your code is well written, and the mistake you made is one that a lot of beginners make.